# Completing the converse of the theorem.

Tags: general-topology

**Definition:-**
Let $(X,\mathscr T)$ be a topological space. A basis for $\mathscr T$ is a subcollection $\mathscr B$ of $\mathscr T$ with the property that if $U\in \mathscr T$ then $U=\phi$ or there is a subcollection $\mathscr B'$ of $\mathscr B$ such that $U=\cup \{B:B\in \mathscr B'\}.$

**Question:-**

A family $\mathscr B$ of subsets of $X$ such that $\mathscr B$ is a basis for the topology $\mathscr T$ on $X$ iff: (1) $X=\{B:B\in \mathscr B\}$,and (2) if $B_1,B_2 \in \mathscr B$ and $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, then there exists $B\in \mathscr B$ such that $x\in   B$ and $B\subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

**My attempt:-** 
Assume a family $\mathscr B$ of subsets of $X$ such that $\mathscr B$ is a basis for the topology $\mathscr T$ on $X.$  We know that $X\in \mathscr T.$ We assume that $\mathscr B$ is a basis for the topology $\mathscr T$ on $X.$ there is a subcollection $\mathscr B'$ of $\mathscr B$ such that $X=\cup \{B:B\in \mathscr B'\}\subset \cup \{B:B\in \mathscr B\}\subset X .$ Hence, (1) holds. For proving (2), we have $\mathscr B \subset \mathscr T.$ So, $B_1, B_2\in \mathscr T$. Hence, $B_1 \cap B_2 \in \mathscr T$. So, there exists a subcollection $\mathscr B"$ such that  $B_1 \cap B_2=\{B:B\in \mathscr B"\}.$ So there exists $B\in \mathscr B"\subset \mathscr B$ which contains x and contained in $B_1\cap B_2$.

I have problem on proving on the converse.

Assume (1) and (2). $X\in \mathscr T$, $X=\{B:B\in \mathscr B\}$(given). If we need to prove for $A\neq X$ and $A\neq \phi.$ I am not able to proceed further. How do I complete the proof? Please help me.

Comment: See for example "Munkres's Topology, section 13 - Basis for a Topology".

Comment: are you talking about lemma 13.1?

Comment: Not just that, the fine details of his definition is very important for that lemma too.

Comment: for each $x \in A$ an element $B_x \in \mathscr B$ such that $x \in B_x \subset A$. This condition is not granded. Else it is easy to prove.

Comment: Read carefully how he defines the generated topology by a basis. His starting point is very different than yours, but at the end, he arrives at what you desire.

Comment: I am reading from topology by Patty. Once, I studied from Munkres. Now it is confusing :(

Comment: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303359/are-these-two-definitions-of-basis-equivalent). Also, note that your definition of base of topology is equivalent to the first definition in this post (it's really easy to prove this latter equivalence).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\mathcal{B}$ obeys (1) and (2).

Then define $\mathcal{T} = \{ \cup \mathcal{B}': \mathcal{B}' \subseteq \mathcal{B}\}$.

Then $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $X$: $X \in \mathcal{T}$ because of (1), while $\mathcal{B}' = \emptyset$ (a valid choice, likewise you don't need the $U= \emptyset$ condition in the question), shows that $\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}$.

That $\mathcal{T}$ is closed under finite intersections follows from (2), intersection of two sets suffice; while closedness under unions is trivial (a union of unions of subfamilies is a union of a subfamily...).

And by definition $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for $\mathcal{T}$.

It's not really a converse in the classical sense: if a family $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of a **set** $X$ (no topology yet) obeys the conditions (1) and (2), we can *define* a topology $\mathcal{T}$ that has $\mathcal{B}$ as a base, which is what I did above. The left to right part, which you did, shows that these conditions are necessary to be a base for a topology, as any base for any topology on $X$ obeys them. (But that topology is not mentioned anymore in the conditions; it's abstracted away as it were.)

Comment: How do I prove that $\mathscr T = \mathcal{T}$?

Comment: @Mathgeek It's obvious.

Comment: You cannot prove the converse as it is stated. $\mathscr{T}$ doesn't appear in (1) or (2) so you can't possibly deduce anything about it from them. The theorem you want is, $\mathscr{B}$ is a basis for $\tt a$ topology on X iff (1) and (2). Henno has shown how to prove that.

Comment: @Mathgeek I added some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the converse: Let $\mathscr B$  satisfy (1) and (2) and  define to be $\{\cup B:B\subset  \mathscr B\}.$

(I). Assume that we have shown that $\cup T\in \mathscr T$ whenever $T\subset  \mathscr T.$

Regarding the intersection of a finite subset of $\mathscr T$:

(II). From (2),   by induction on $n\in \Bbb N,$ if $\{b_1,...,b_n\} \subset  \mathscr B$ and $p\in \cap_{j=1}^n b_j$ then there exists $b\in \mathscr B$ such that $p\in b\subset \cap_{i=1}^nb_i.$ Therefore $\cap_{i=1}^nb_i \in \mathscr T.$

(III). Now let $n\in \Bbb N$ and $A=\{A_1,...,A_n\}\subset  \mathscr T.$ We want to show that $\cap A\in  \mathscr T.$

For $i=1,...n $ let $A_i=\cup B_i$ where  $B_i\subset \mathscr B.$ We have $$\bullet  \quad\cap A=\cup \{\cap_{i=1}^n b_i: b_1\in B_1\land...\land b_n\in B_n\}.$$

Now if $(b_1\in B_1\land...\land b_n\in B_n)$ then $\{b_i:i=1,...,n\}\subset \mathscr B$ so by (II) we have $\cap_{j=1}^nb_i\in \mathscr T.$ Applying this to $\bullet$ we see that $\cap A$ is the union of a collection of members of $\mathscr T,$ so by (I) we have  $\cap A\in \mathscr T.$

Remarks: (1).In your definition, the phrase " $U=\emptyset$ or " is redundant. A sub-collection $\mathscr B'$ of $\mathscr B$ means a subset  of $\mathscr B.$ This includes the case $\mathscr B'=\emptyset.$ And of course $\cup \emptyset =\emptyset.$..(2). Many authors say base instead of basis. The word basis has (multiple) other meanings in the context of vector spaces, so when discussing topological vector spaces, it may be better to use "base".

Comment: There are many constructions where we have a base  $B$  such that  $b\cap b'\in B$ whenever $b,b'\in B$ and $b,b' $ are not disjoint. For example the set of non-empty bounded real intervals with rational end-points.